# Change a Specific Value to a Lagged Value in r

Tags: r

I have a time series with values at Time = 23:00:00 that are always wrong, so I need to change those values.

Sample Data:

```
data <- data.table(
    Time =c("20:47:00","20:52:00","21:25:00","22:25:00","23:00:00","01:02:00"),
    Open = c(21.306,21.305,21.305,21.300,22.900,21.286),
    TotalVolume = c(5,20,15,11,19,4) 
    )
```

Which looks like:

```
   Time        Open     TotalVolume
1: 20:47:00    21.306    5
2: 20:52:00    21.305    20
3: 21:25:00    21.305    15
4: 22:25:00    21.300    11
5: 23:00:00    22.900    19
6: 01:02:00    21.286    4
```

I would like to replace the Open value when Time = 23:00:00 with the Open value immediately preceding it. Which should look like this:

```
   Time        Open     TotalVolume
1: 20:47:00    21.306    5
2: 20:52:00    21.305    20
3: 21:25:00    21.305    15
4: 22:25:00    21.300    11
5: 23:00:00    21.300    19
6: 01:02:00    21.286    4
```

I have tried using the lag function without the desired results:

```
data$Open[data$Time == "23:00:00"] <- lag(data,1)
```

and

```
data$Open[data$Time == "23:00:00"] <- lag(data$Open[data$Time == "23:00:00"],1)
```

Comment: If you already using `data.table`, you might want to take a look at `data.table::shift`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> n <- which(data$Time=="23:00:00")
> data$Open[n] <- data$Open[n-1]
> data
       Time   Open TotalVolume
1: 20:47:00 21.306           5
2: 20:52:00 21.305          20
3: 21:25:00 21.305          15
4: 22:25:00 21.300          11
5: 23:00:00 21.300          19
6: 01:02:00 21.286           4
>
```

`n` contains the position(s) where the Time is "23:00:00", so n-1 are the positions immediately preceeding the "23:00:00"-positions. Hence the assignment `data$Open[n] <- data$Open[n-1]` does what we want.

Comment: This will only modify the first row where '23:00:00' occurs. And, if there is no occurrence of this value, the code won't work.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: @user3949008: Now it work, no matter how many "23:00:00" there are. Are you willing to revoke your downvote?

Comment: This works great, thanks! In the data set there are lots of "23:00:00" observations. I will also need to change several other variables that go with the "23:00:00" observations, so this is the most robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
library(dplyr)
> data <- data.table(
+     Time =c("20:47:00","20:52:00","21:25:00","22:25:00","23:00:00","01:02:00"),
+     Open = c(21.306,21.305,21.305,21.300,22.900,21.286),
+     TotalVolume = c(5,20,15,11,19,4) 
+ )
> data <- data %>% mutate(Open = ifelse(Time == '23:00:00', lag(Open), Open))
> data
       Time   Open TotalVolume
1: 20:47:00 21.306           5
2: 20:52:00 21.305          20
3: 21:25:00 21.305          15
4: 22:25:00 21.300          11
5: 23:00:00 21.300          19
6: 01:02:00 21.286           4
```

You can also use this way without the dplyr mutate function like this:

```
> data <- data.table(
+     Time =c("20:47:00","20:52:00","21:25:00","22:25:00","23:00:00","01:02:00"),
+     Open = c(21.306,21.305,21.305,21.300,22.900,21.286),
+     TotalVolume = c(5,20,15,11,19,4) 
+ )
> data$Open <- ifelse(data$Time == '23:00:00', lag(data$Open), data$Open)
> data
       Time   Open TotalVolume
1: 20:47:00 21.306           5
2: 20:52:00 21.305          20
3: 21:25:00 21.305          15
4: 22:25:00 21.300          11
5: 23:00:00 21.300          19
6: 01:02:00 21.286           4
```

Comment: You are using `dplyr` in both solutions.

Comment: Sorry, you are right that lag is from that package. I edited to clarify. Thank you for the catch.